# canvas drawimage draw zoomed image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I need to set canvas size using code and than drawImage on this canvas. The problem is drawn image is zoomed.

code follows -

```
currentImageDIV = $("#cnv").css({ "position" : "relative" ,"height": 400, "width": 800,"top" :"100px" , "border": "1px solid red" });

var c = document.getElementById("cnv");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;

var img = new Image();
img.src = "/images/sample2.jpg";
img.onload = function () {
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); 
}
```

If I do not set the canvas size than image drawn as expected, not zoomed.

How can I control the canvas size without drawImage zoomed image ?

Answer (score 2):

I found out that if I hard code the **width** and **height** of the canvas tag than no zooming is taking place.

Another solution for this is to set the width and height using **prop** rather than **css** (e.g. *$("#cnv").prop({"width": 800, "height": 600});*)