# canvas.drawImage() renders only the top half of the source image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I am trying to make a JS image cropper from scratch. I get the cropping part pretty much okay, but when I try to render the cropped section of the image into a canvas using `drawImage()`, the output displays only the top half of the image. Any idea what might be wrong?

CodePen link: https://codepen.io/virtuoso/full/MxrWrN

Comment: Just a FIY: your image is not loading in your codepen. I see the standard image not found icon in my browser.

Comment: @Mathyn I saw it too. But when I switched to the edit mode and refresh the preview iframe it worked..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Canvas image is not the same size as the canvas or orginal image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54572212/canvas-image-is-not-the-same-size-as-the-canvas-or-orginal-image)

Comment: @JackU This is different, because that one had the `width` and `height` attributes of the `<canvas>` element set. My problem was that I was not setting those attributes.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution from this post: [canvas drawimage draw zoomed image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42944192/canvas-drawimage-draw-zoomed-image)

The problem was that I was changing the `<canvas>`  element's `style` attribute to set its width and height, when I should have used its `width` and `height` attributes instead.